# How to fix netifaces module installation for python2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, network-programming, pip, python-netifaces

Environment : Kali Linux 2

I started reading this book "Python network programming cookbook" and the writers listed few modules I am gonna need during the book i was able to install all of them except #netifaces, I tried both the "pip install netifaces" and "python setup.py install" methods but both made appear this message:

```
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1': execvp: No such file or directory

error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-lsf_5N/netifaces/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-TsHwUh-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-lsf_5N/netifaces
Storing debug log for failure in /root/.pip/pip.log
```

I tried to install python-dev and all the libraries I could find in previous asked questions here but nothing made it happen

Thank you all for your help

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing gcc, which is needed to compile netifaces.

I've never used Kali Linux before but you should have apt so, you can try: `sudo apt-get install gcc` to install the missing package.

Hopefully this solves your problem.